# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath' on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

hi recently I upgrade and flutter to v2 and my android studio too but after that my flutter app gives a Gradle error and cant be extracted I tried too hard to do many solutions like but maven in dependency but it still gives an error.the gradle version is now 5.6 or something and one more thing all the application running well still which i made before upgrade and its gradle version is
Please help me out and the error is given below.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\dell.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.96\descriptors\com.android.tools\annotations\27.1.0\11cd36a7dcab7d14d0c14c5e6c7582e3\descriptor.bin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Try run the studio as admin.

Comment: i dont understand** i am doing flutter on vs code *** run vs code as admin???

Comment: Yes, try run your IDE as admin, for me I need to run the android studio as admin to work some parts.

Comment: i did but not work now even i run on android studio but the error is same . its really sucks i run the android studio as admin still no effect. please help me out

Comment: Did you try flutter clean on terminal already?